# how to use 'BETWEEN' condetion two times in one sql statement for same column or diffrent columns

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby, between, javadb

this is sql statement give only one value

```
SELECT count(pn1) FROM pledges
WHERE date1
BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06'
```

i want use "between" more than one time for same column or for different columns in same table

for example  i want use it in date1 more than one time or i want use it for date1 and date2 with different range

NOTE:I'm using java DB Derpy(JDBC-Derby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More than once for the same column:

```
SELECT count(pn1) 
    FROM pledges
    WHERE date1 BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06'
       OR date1 BETWEEN '2011-07-05' AND '2011-08-06'
```

Two different columns:

```
SELECT count(pn1) 
    FROM pledges
    WHERE date1 BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06'
      AND date2 BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06'
```

**EDIT**: Based on comment, perhaps you're looking for something like this instead?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN date1 BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS Count1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date1 BETWEEN '2011-07-05' AND '2011-08-06' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS Count2
    FROM pledges
    WHERE date1 BETWEEN '2011-05-05' AND '2011-06-06'
       OR date1 BETWEEN '2011-07-05' AND '2011-08-06'
```

Comment: no i didn't mean that..i want see two results.. in my query i can see one result also in your query but i want 2 results for example..the current query give me 6 as result and i want see 6 and 8 as results